# Failed to create GitHub repository

Tags: java, github, intellij-idea

I am trying to import my project into the github but I am getting an error:

Failed to create GitHub repository.
Can't create repository: MyProjectName Not Found - Not Found

I am trying to share my project from IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.3.
Also I am using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `MyProjectName` directory, issue the command `git init`. That should initialize the repository.

Comment: Thanks! That helped.